# Autocomplete doesn't work after updating jquery-ui version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I updated jquery-ui from an old version to 1.10.3 and now autocomplete 
In the firebug's console window I can see the query result from the server as json but I can't see the widget. After checking - It seems that everything is working but the widget stays with "display: none".

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: function (request, response) {
                response(valueAccessor().source(request.term));
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                allBindingsAccessor().value(ui.item.label);
                if (valueAccessor().afterSelect) {
                     valueAccessor().afterSelect(allBindingsAccessor().value);
                }
                $(this).blur();
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to jquery-ui-1.10.4 and it worked.

Comment: I looked all over and finally found your post. Thank you for providing your own answer.